# Datetime picker does not show current year (WPF)?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I am creating a xabp application which have a datepicker control. I wanted to display the current date on it by default, and wrote the following code which worked as intended:

```
     <DatePicker Height="25" SelectedDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayDate="" Margin="181,141,0,0" Name="DatePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" IsTodayHighlighted="False"
```

Though it displays the current date, but when I want to select the another date it display year like this. Follow the image please.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `DisplayDate=""` or give it a real date (e.g. `DisplayDate="3/15/2009"`) it will work.